# Insert data from JSON to html elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, loops

I have JSON file with 3 objects:

```
[
  {
    "image": "assets/image.jpg",
    "title": "Text",
    "text": "Some text",
    "date": "23/11/2013"
  },
 ... 
]
```

And 3 HTML elements:

```
<div class="blog-post">
  <img src="" class="blog-image"/>
  <h2 class="blog-title"></h2>
  <p class="blog-text"></p>
  <div class="blog-date"></div>
</div>
```

I know how to fetch datas from 1 object to 1 html element:

```
((() => {
  const getJSON = (url, callback) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      const status = xhr.status;
      if (status === 200) {
        callback(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        callback(status);
      }
    };
    xhr.send();
  };

  const blogTitle = document.querySelector('.blog-title');
  const blogText = document.querySelector('.blog-text');
  const blogDate = document.querySelector('.blog-date');
  const blogImage = document.querySelector('.blog-image');

  getJSON('/test-data.json', (err, data) => {
    if (err != null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      blogImage.src = data.image;
      blogTitle.innerText = data.title;
      blogText.innerText = data.text;
      blogDate.innerText = data.date;
    }
  });
}))();
```

But how can i make loop around all objects in json file and insert datas to html elements?

Comment: Do you multiple DIV elements of class `blog-post`? If so, how do you determine which JSON data array entry goes with which `.blog-post` division? Or do you need to create new divisions for each entry in  JSON data?

Comment: I have multiple DIV elements with blog-post class. Probably, create two arrays and append [i] > [i], but i have no idea what the best way to resolve this problem - this why i create a question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your JSON file will return an array, and we can loop through the array like this:

```
getJSON('./test-data.json', (err, data) => {
  if (err != null) {
    return false;
  } else {
    data.forEach(obj => {
      createElements(obj);
    });
  }
});
```

That createElements is a function I wrote:

```
function createElements(obj) {
  const mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
  mainDiv.classList.add('blog-post');
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.classList.add('blog-image');
  img.src = obj['image'];
  const title = document.createElement('h2');
  title.classList.add('blog-title');
  title.innerHTML = obj['title'];
  const text = document.createElement('p');
  text.classList.add('blog-text');
  text.innerHTML = obj['text'];
  const date = document.createElement('div');
  date.classList.add('blog-date');
  date.innerHTML = obj['date'];
  mainDiv.appendChild(img);
  mainDiv.appendChild(title);
  mainDiv.appendChild(text);
  mainDiv.appendChild(date);
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(mainDiv);
}
```

Pretty verbose, but this will add a new post to the HTML body for every object in your JSON array with the correct classes. You can change the last line of the createElements function to append it to a different element than the body.

Comment: looks so dirty but work. so thank you, Andrew, for fast help.

Comment: Yeah it's gonna look pretty ugly whenever you add HTML elements through Javascript. That's where something like React really comes in handy.